# Showing a fullscreen picture opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, display

I want to show an image in a fullscreen window with opencv and I managed to achieve that, but if the image is smaller than the screen resolution, it gets stretched. Is there any way I can show it without it being stretched? Also I want to start drawing the image from the top left corner. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you obviously know about `namedWindow`, right? then you know it takes flags. [try them all](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d90/group__highgui__window__flags.html#gabf7d2c5625bc59ac130287f925557ac3). use AUTOSIZE, then the image won't be scaled or stretched. you can additionally use FULLSCREEN, or just maximize the window.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz tried all of them, they either stretch my image or the image is not in full screen anymore

Comment: Also I don’t want any borders visible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yeah that can be difficult. it strongly depends on the GUI "backend" code, what features it actually implements. on windows, you'd get the picture, 1:1, aligned top left, with dark gray background. you seem to not be on windows, or you got a build with Qt backend. -- you may have to make your own rudimentary GUI for the exact thing you need. or submit issues to opencv's github and hope someone will do something about them... there are plans to completely overhaul the GUI in OpenCV.

Comment: Ok thanks, as it looks I’m going to try drawing a black box on the whole screen and then display the picture in borderless window.